# jhipster and kubernetes and consul not working

Tags: kubernetes, jhipster, consul

When I tried deploying my application to a kubernetes cluster using the jhipster kubernetes generator, the consul pod is not working correctly. the replicat zero of the pod can ping to self using ping consul-0.consul.default.svc.cluster.local.

however, it can't ping the other 2 replicas. Also, the replica one can't ping consul-1.consul.default.svc.default.local. I don't understand why only the zero  replica works to ping itself while the 1 and 2 can't ping themself. don't hesitate to ask more info for the problem :)

thanks

Comment: Which JHipster version are you using ?

Comment: thx but i've solved the problem... it was kubernetes dns that had an intermittend problem